# iOS UITableViewBackground Image Centered

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a background image from a designer that was made for iPhone 5 screens which I'd like to use as the backdrop for my TableView. The image is larger than it should be on older iPhones though, and gets condensed, which causes it to look strange. Is there a way I can make it centered in the TV without resizing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `contentMode` on the UITableView's `backgroundView` to `UIViewContentModeCenter` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.